# Recommended laptop with docking port for 2 monitors, compatible with elementary OS?

Tags: display, laptop

I plan on using a laptop so I can stay on the go.  However, while I'm at home I have a need for multiple monitors.

Is elementary OS known to support multiple monitors?  What is a good laptop + docking station that you recommend?

Comment: Don't ask others to recommend things on this site. This is a  Q / A site and not a recommendation site

Comment: Yes, elementary **does** support multiple monitors.

Comment: I apologize for that. I did a search for elementary OS compatibility and found very minimal results. I understand it supports multiple monitors, but didn't want to lose out on an incompatible purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Elementary OS does support multiple monitors, I myself I have 2 more monitors, and a Lenovo G580 laptop. Its works quite well.

You'll find the monitor setup quite glitchy, and each time when you'll boot up the computer you'll lose your monitor configuration for some reason.
Keep in mind that Elementary OS is still in Beta.

Color calibration might give you some trouble too.